# Python Get google information by search

Tags: python, google-search

I want to create a program that could get information asked by the user from google and print the awnser on the screen. For example: "Who is the president of the US?" must return "Donald Trump".

Here is the code I used so far:

```
from googlesearch.googlesearch import GoogleSearch
response = GoogleSearch().search("Who is the president of the US?")
for result in response.results:
    print("Title: " + result.title)
    print("Content: " + result.getText())
```

But that returns an empty `response.results`!
With every word I fill in to search I get this empty `response.results`.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the answer I am looking for on Google:
[image]

How can I get that awnser?

Comment: if you want to use Google Search to get answer then it can be better to use full text `"Who is the president of the US?"`. Google will use own system to recognize content and to give better answer.

Comment: Okay, but how can I get the data from Google?

Comment: you could use [requests](https://2.python-requests.org/) and [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to get web page and search in HTML but Google doesn't like scripts/bots and sometimes it can make big problem to get something. Sometimes it can be easier to use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser and get HTML from Selenium.

Comment: But how can I find the sender, I mean.... It could be 70 years or 71 years, so I don't know what my search word is!?

Comment: I don't understand what you ask.

Comment: I have updated my question!

Comment: Google makes big money on people visiting its page so it doesn't like scripts which not click advertisments and don't give money to Google. And this is why it can send empty results. This code could work correctly few months ago but now Google can block it and you can't change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the python `google-search` module? first you will have to `pip install google-search`, then try this

```py
from googlesearch.googlesearch import GoogleSearch
response = GoogleSearch().search("something")
for result in response.results:
    print("Title: " + result.title)
    print("Content: " + result.getText())
```

Comment: does the response instance have anything else in it?